# spring data rest endpoint not exposed on aws

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I  have deployed my application on  aws elasticbeanstalk  , when I access this [url](http://springfullstack-env-1.eba-m4suzyhc.ap-south-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/api), it shows all the repository of application but when I access the same url after sometime
 the following json is displayed without the method exposed in my repository :

```
    {
      "_links" : {
        "profile" : {
          "href" : "http://springfullstack-env-1.eba-m4suzyhc.ap-south-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/api/profile"
        }
      }
    }
```

When I  restart my ebs app on aws then it shows all the repository again.

Here is the main method class

```
    import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

    @SpringBootApplication
    public class SpringBootEcommerceApplication {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(SpringBootEcommerceApplication.class, args);
        }

    }
```

Here is my entity class

```
    package com.mycode.ecommerce.entity;

    import lombok.Data;
    import org.hibernate.annotations.CreationTimestamp;
    import org.hibernate.annotations.UpdateTimestamp;

    import javax.persistence.*;
    import java.math.BigDecimal;
    import java.util.Date;

    @Entity
    @Table(name="product")
    @Data
    public class Product {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "id")
        private Long id;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "category_id", nullable = false)
        private ProductCategory category;

        @Column(name = "sku")
        private String sku;

        @Column(name = "name")
        private String name;

        @Column(name = "description")
        private String description;

        @Column(name = "unit_price")
        private BigDecimal unitPrice;

        @Column(name = "image_url")
        private String imageUrl;

        @Column(name = "active")
        private boolean active;

        @Column(name = "units_in_stock")
        private int unitsInStock;

        @Column(name = "date_created")
        @CreationTimestamp
        private Date dateCreated;

        @Column(name = "last_updated")
        @UpdateTimestamp
        private Date lastUpdated;
    }
```

Here is my repository class

```
    package com.mycode.ecommerce.dao;

    import com.mycode.ecommerce.entity.Product;
    import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
    import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
    import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

    @CrossOrigin
    public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Long> {

        Page<Product> findByCategoryId(@RequestParam("id") Long id, Pageable pageable);

        Page<Product> findByNameContaining(@RequestParam("name") String name, Pageable pageable);

    }
```